# How to get stored procedure as IQueryable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, linq-to-entities, where-clause

I want to get my stored procedure from entity in case I can use like this:

```
var WagonQuery = db.spGetTravelBYRTravelInfo(DepartureDate, FromId, ToId);

if (WagonId != 0)
    WagonQuery = WagonQuery.Where(p => p.WagonID == WagonId); // HERE IS ERROR. Wagonquery Can Not Uses Like forexample List,So I Can Filter It And Use Several Where Clauses

grdTravels.DataSource = WagonQuery;
grdTravels.DataBind();
```

Here is the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Should Convert it to list and then(Just Like This) :

```
        List<spGetTravelBYRTravelInfo_Result> lst = db.spGetTravelBYRTravelInfo(DepartureDate, FromId, ToId).ToList();
    var dt = lst.Select(p => p);
    if (WagonId != 0)
        dt = dt.Where(p => p.WagonID == WagonId);
    if (ddlReserved.SelectedValue == "t")
        dt = dt.Where(p => p.Presell > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not figure out what your stored procedure returns. In my project using EF 6.1.3 by doing following  you can filter a list dynamically from database

```
 List<SparePart> spSpares = db.Database.SqlQuery<SparePart>("spGetSparePartsFromProductId " + Convert.ToString(productId) + "," + Convert.ToString(subProduct));
```

Where my model is

```
 public partial class SparePart
    {
        public long ItemID { get; set; }
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> ItemPrice { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public string ItemDesc { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ItemGroup { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string MajorCategory { get; set; }
        public string MinorCategory { get; set; }
        public string UOM { get; set; }
    }
```

and stored procedure

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[spGetSparePartsFromProductId]
(
@productId bigint,
@subproductId bigint=0
)
AS
BEGIN
if @productId=1 
select * from SpareParts
END 
GO
```

Which yields same as SpareParts table

[image: Same as Model]

may be some help